# Play mp3 music from a local Folder? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want my bot to play multiple songs after each other. All I have is my bot playing one song and then stopping to do it. My Code so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def startq(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(705831663497904211)
    vc = await channel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("E:\Programmieren\Programmieren\Disc-Bot\music2.mp3"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the songs you want in the `songs` list, after that it should play all the songs.

You can also scan all the files in the folder and add them to the list using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Note: I have not tried it, but it should work theoretically.

```py
import glob

@bot.command()
async def startq(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(705831663497904211)
    vc = await channel.connect()
    
    songs = ["music2.mp3","music1.mp3"]
    # or check all files in folder
    songs = glob.glob("E:\Programmieren\Programmieren\Disc-Bot\*.mp3")
    for song in songs:
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"E:\Programmieren\Programmieren\Disc-Bot\{song}"))
        while vc.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This code doesn't look like it plays song after song... or does it?

Comment: But let me try it :D

Comment: It plays one song and gives me this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already playing audio.
I think it is because this code starts one song and the instantly wants to start the next song...

Comment: Thank you very much :D